# Why df output is different than lsblk for specific partition

Tags: centos

Why `/` partition is not 100GB?

```
[root@api ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda    253:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─vda1 253:1    0   99G  0 part /
└─vda2 253:2    0    1G  0 part [SWAP]

[root@api ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       2.0G  1.4G  507M  73% /
devtmpfs        489M     0  489M   0% /dev
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           497M   13M  484M   3% /run
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           497M   13M  484M   3% /etc/machine-id
```

Comment: `resize2fs /dev/vda1` solved this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your partition `/dev/vda1` is 99 GB, but the filesystem on it is only 2 GB. You can use `resize2fs /dev/vda1` to grow the filesystem on the partition.

Related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/701806/confused-about-df-and-lsblk-commands-showing-different-information).